# Imagery on March 6, 2014 @ Lat 42dd55'22" N, Long 079dd37'36" W

Tags: imagery, satellite, aerial-photography

I am looking for any advice where to find imagery on March 6, 2014 (or a few days following) for: [image: location]

I have searched the [USGS](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/), [ImageHunter](http://imagehunter.apollomapping.com/), and [Digital Globe](http://geofuse.geoeye.com/maps/Map.aspx) with no luck.

Does anyone have a resource where I can find imagery for Dunnville Ontario on March 6, 2014?

---

There was a fire on this day and I am looking for before/after imagery. See this article by the hamilton spectator about the fire.

[Dunnville ‘in shock’ over Rosa Flora fire](http://www.thespec.com/news-story/4404026-dunnville-in-shock-over-rosa-flora-fire/)

Comment: What information are you trying to get from the imagery? If burned area then perhaps use MODIS product MOD14A1 or MYD14A1. These are daily images with a spatial resolution of 1000 meters.

Comment: Hey,
I am looking to create a before and after. I am not sure that 1000m resolution will work but I will take a look. Here is the location of the building and the rough size on [google earth](https://maps.google.ca/maps?q=42.9228,+-79.6267&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x882cc43d837ba8e9:0xb1380e9d1fb02632,42.9228,+-79.6267&gl=ca&ei=jvIdU5qANYqarAHq94CIDA&ved=0CCYQ8gEwAA)

Comment: I don't think you will be able to find what you are looking for (high-resolution, daily images) among the free sources available.

Comment: I am totally willing to pay if there are any good resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a non exhaustive list of sites where you could find images :

- [SPOT images catalog](http://sirius.spotimage.com/PageSearch.aspx?language=UK&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) (SPOT and Formasat and Pleiade) high resolution to very high resolution
- [Rapid eye](http://www.blackbridge.com/rapideye/products/eyefind.htm) 5 m
- [DMC](http://catalogue.dmcii.com/) high resolution

For very high resolution, you can look at the archives from Ikonos, GeoEye, Quickbird, Worldview or Pleiades.

However, I guess that Image Hunter knows all these sites. So here are the alternatives :

- you can order one image if you are ready to pay for it. If you are lucky, satellites like Pleiade could provide you with an image within a week.
- you can wait for the next Landsat 8, there is one every 16 days (in theory)
- you have daily images from MODIS (250 m for red and near, the 500 m and more) and from SPOT vegetation (1 km , not sure the daly are available). [PROBA-V](http://proba-v.vgt.vito.be/) could also help with its 333 m resolution.